# Can a class be declared static in c++?

Tags: c++, static

Is this legal in c++ (yes i know it's legal in .net), and if so, how/why would it be used?

```
static class foo{  
    public:  
        foo();  
        int doIt(int a);   
};
```

Comment: "yes i know it's legal in .net" Not true. In C++/CLI static classes are declared as `ref class MyClass abstract sealed`, not `static class MyClass` (It's the C# syntax).

Answer (score 30):

If you're using C++/CLI, the actual syntax for `static` is

```
ref class Foo abstract sealed /* abstract sealed = C# static */
{
};
```

Comment: +1 This is **the correct answer**. By marking a class as such, attempting to instantiate the class in C# with `var f = Foo();` will give the expected errors *"Cannot declare a variable of static type Foo"* and *"Cannot create an instance of the static class Foo"*, indicating that C# considers it a (C#) "static" class.

Answer (score 22):

No, this isn't supported in C++. The only thing the `static` specifier does in .NET is force you to make all the class members static; it's just a helper keyword. To write a static class in C++, all you need to do is make sure each member in the class is marked as `static`. (Edit: and a non-public constructor, so your "static" class can't be instantiated.)

Comment: You also need a non-public (ideally private) constructor.

Comment: Ah, yes. I knew I was forgetting something!

Comment: Normally, this would be in a namespace.

Comment: There are situations when you make it a class. To use as a policy in a template for example.

Comment: This answer is wrong. C# `static` keyword adds metadata that make a class `abstract` and `sealed` so even if you reference an assembly with that class you can't instantiate the class or derive from it.

Comment: -1 Agree with Dmitry. [Dan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1635095/119527) below is correct (see my comment as well).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that's only the correct answer if OP is using C++/CLI. If they're using plain (unmanaged) C++, then Dan's answer doesn't apply. (Also, way to dig up an almost-five-year-old questions!)

Comment: @AdamMaras Wow... did I really miss that? Apparently I was under the false assumption that the OP was asking about C++/CLI. Very sorry. (And I dug it up because I was trying to figure this out, in C++/CLI, of course).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart no worries.

Answer (score 8):

The `static` modifier at file-level scope in C++ indicates that the identifier marked `static` is only visible in the file in which it is defined. This syntax is not available in on classes (only methods and variables), but a similar effect can be obtained for classes using an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace{
  class Foo{};
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The closest equivalent of a static class in C++ is a class with only static member variables. This is known as the [monostate](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16361/1954?pf=true) pattern.  Such a class means that all instances of this class will have the same state. The usage syntax of a monostate instance is similar to a normal class (unlike a singleton class), and indeed a monostate class can be converted to a regular class without changing any of its usages. E.g.

```
// Monostate class
public class Administrator
{
  private:
    static int _userId;
  public:
    int UserId() { return _userId; }
}

// Initializing the monostate value
int Administrator::_userId = 42;

// Using an instance of a monostate class
void Foo()
{
    Administrator admin = new Administrator();
    Assert.Equals( 42, admin.UserId() );   // will always be 42 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `static` is for objects and functions.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the following thread, C++ doesn't support a static class.

If you mean a class with no public constructor and only static variables then you can read this thread.

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread122285.html#

Answer (score 0):

A class cannot be `static`.  For the static class in other language, declare a class with only `static` members.

The `static` before class declaration attributes the immediately constructed object, mostly useful with anonymous classes;

```
static class Foo {} foo;
```

`Foo`, the name of the class here, is optional.