# C++ declaring a managed variable in a native code

Tags: visual-c++, variables, native, global, managed

I have a .NET form, and a native code in my Visual Studio. The problem is: I can't declare a global instance of my .NET form in my native code, like this:

```
Editor^ maineditor;
```

It gives me this problem:

```
error C3145: 'EditorEntry' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'Cube3D::Editor ^'
```

Comment: The MSDN article for C3145 documents this error well.  And also gives the workaround, make it a static member of ref class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using a global static try making it a static method in a container type

```
ref class ManagedGlobals {
  public:
  static Editor^ maineditor = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: THanks, but when i define editor, the second code this comes: a variable with static storage duration cannot have a handle or tracking reference type

Comment: And when compiling: 'editor' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'Cube3D::Editor ^'

Comment: @user1492812 oops, didn't realize that was an issue. Removed that part of the answer

Comment: Any ideas?, Im sorry for the misconception. EditorEntry was the previous name for my instance of the Editor, sorry about that :/

Answer (score 10):

wrap the handle with a gcroot<> struct

```
gcroot<Editor^> maineditor;
```

Comment: Works like a charm and cleaner than creating a dummy wrapper class :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have your static class up top (referece: [Can a class be declared static in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635068/can-a-class-be-declared-static-in-c))

```
ref class ManagedGlobals abstract sealed {
public:
    static Excel::Application^ xl;
};
```

Now just reference that class

```
ManagedGlobals::xl = gcnew Excel::Application();
```