# What is a static class?

Tags: c++, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a class be declared static in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635068/can-a-class-be-declared-static-in-c)

I put `static` before `class`, it is okay. But what does it mean?

```
static class A
{
public:
    void F();

private:
    int i;
};
```

Comment: Fixing the missing semicolon, `source.cpp:8:1: error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions`. Perhaps that gives you a clue.

Comment: How'd you get that to compile?

Comment: No, `static class A {};` is not okay.  But `static class A {} x;` is....